# Will switching to OpenGL improve rendering speeds?

Tags: android, opengl-es, surfaceview

I have made some simple benchmarks for my game.

It turns out the average time spent in my updateGame() function is: 1-4 ms

Average time spent in my renderGame() function: 15-17ms.

I use a SurfaceView and a dirty rect. However the size of the dirty rect does not seem to affect performance which is strange.

Anyhow, the renderGame() function is the bottleneck here and keeps me from achieveing the 45-60 FPS I need.
I also use a Samsung S4 Mini so it is a fairly powerful phone so bottom end phones it will be even worse.

My render function looks like this:

```
@Override
public void render( double interpolation, Canvas canvas )
{
    canvas.drawColor( Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR );

    canvas.drawBitmap( background, null, backgroundRect, null );

    for ( int i = 0; i < theGameEdges.length; i++ )
    {
        theGameEdges[ i ].draw( canvas );
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < obstacles.length; i++ )
    {
        obstacles[ i ].draw( canvas );
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < holes.length; i++ )
    {
        holes[ i ].draw( canvas );
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < goalFlags.length; i++ )
    {
        goalFlags[ i ].draw( canvas );
    }

    balls = level.getBallPositions();
    for ( int i = 0; i < balls.length; i++ )
    {
        SilverBallRect[ i ].set(
                balls[ i ].X + theOffsetX,
                balls[ i ].Y + theOffsetTopY,
                balls[ i ].X + ballSize + theOffsetX,
                balls[ i ].Y + ballSize + theOffsetTopY
        );

        canvas.drawBitmap( SilverBall, null, SilverBallRect[ i ], null );
    }

    stringBuilder.setLength( 0 );
    stringBuilder.append( timeString ).append( engine.getTimeSeconds() );

    canvas.drawText( stringBuilder, 0, stringBuilder.length(), textX, textY, theTextPaint );
}
```

1. Could I improve the performance here by using OpenGL?
2. Can I have different layers in the view or something to improve performance? Don't know how that would work since it is all pixels in the end. but...
3. Any other hints on performance?

Comment: There are several different questions. The one I selected for the title is bullet point #1; however this is a "yes/no/maybe" (and "if you want to rewrite it") that closes down #2. Likewise, if the focus is on how to make surface render faster (ie. not willing to commit to OpenGL) then #2 would be the focus/title and #1 would be closed down. Posts work best when there is a single focus/question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of the dirty rect affects the part of the screen that is updated, not the part that is rendered -- it's not a clip rect.  If you draw pixels outside the dirty rect, they will be drawn, but will not be overwritten when the previous frame is copied into the outside areas.

To get a performance improvement, your code needs to touch only the pixels inside the rect.  Otherwise the areas outside the rect are effectively being drawn twice.

Canvas rendering to a SurfaceView surface is never hardware-accelerated.  You will almost certainly improve performance by using OpenGL ES.  You will also need to learn OpenGL ES, which isn't entirely trivial.

If you want [hardware-accelerated Canvas rendering](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html), you can use a custom View instead of a SurfaceView surface.

**Update:** for software rendering it's even more important to keep the updated pixel count low.  Consider rendering at a lower resolution and upscaling.  See [this article](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/09/using-hardware-scaler-for-performance.html) and the "hardware scaler exerciser" in [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika).

For more details about the Android graphics architecture, see [this document](https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html).

Comment: Thanks, good answer. However if I get the size of the Clip from the canvas it is the same as the dirty rect. So when I do goalFlags[i].draw(canvas) I should actually check if that particular goalFlag is inside the dirty rect and if not then dont draw it?

Comment: It should help.  You can use a quick overlapping-rectangles test to see if the objects to be rendered fall inside the dirty rect.  You can also try using setFixedSize() to reduce the overall pixel count; I added a couple of links to the answer.

Comment: setFixedSize() belongs to what? How would a custom View enable hardware acceleration?

Comment: See the links in the "update" -- it's a SurfaceHolder method.  The View onDraw() method uses a hardware-accelerated Canvas by default.